# After Effects: Javascript - Undefined value used in the expression(Could be out of range array subscript)

Tags: javascript, undefined, after-effects

I'm not a programmer by any means. I'm an animator trying to use JS expressions in After Effects. I'm getting an "Undefined value used in expression" error on line 1 where I define a variable.I already showed it to my friend on discord who is a cs major, and he had no clue what was wrong with it.

[image]
Here's just a paste of the code if you need it:

```
var count = 1;

if (framesToTime(time) % 12 == 0) {
count = count + 1

    if (count % 2 == 0){
        thisProperty = 95
    } else {
    thisProperty = 20
    };
} ;
```

Comment: This part of your code `framesToTime(time)` is not defined, it references a function that's not defined in the snippet you posted here unless there are other parts to your code not here

Comment: @dqve framesToTime is afterEffect's inbuilt function.So no point of problem up there.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with "count declaration"

Answer (score 2):

Ok I don't know why the hell this fixed it, but I changed the name of the variable from "count" to just "x" and it works now. Go figure

Comment: Is count a builtin function in AE perhaps?

Comment: This happened to me, and it turned out to be unbalanced curly braces, which led to a pretty vague error message.

Comment: UPDATE: I see that this error is caused by having a nested if statement, and not having an else that provides a value.  You apparently can't have an if inside of an if without the inner if having an else that sets a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
var count = 1;

if (framesToTime(time) % 12 == 0) {
    count = count + 1;

    if (count % 2 == 0){
        thisProperty = 95;
    } else {
       thisProperty = 20;
    }
}
thisProperty;
```

In your code, thisProperty has become an ordinary variable. If you write its name at the end of the code, then its value will be assigned to the property.

Answer (score 0):

In AE, if there is nothing inside an `if` statement or the `if` statement contains malformed/error code you will receive this error.   Put a temp value inside the curly braces or something to process and ensure nothing inside will throw an error.

I also received this error with this:

```
pastTime = timeToFrames(time)-1;
curPos = transform.xPosition;
pastPos = transform.xPosition.valueAtTime(framesToTime(pastTime));

if (curPos-pastPos[0] != 0) {
```

**// Here is the problem in my case. added a value here `99` to fix until finished testing.**

```
}
else {
        effect("Angle Control")("Angle")
}
```

if/else statements are strict

- The syntax for if/else statements is strict in the JavaScript engine
  and need to be written for standardized JavaScript.

  https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/expression-language-reference.html*

Answer (score -1):

I got this error because there was a missing semicolon.